# Issue using infercnvpy.io.genomic_position_from_gtf

Tags: python, rna-seq, scanpy

I'm trying to use the scanpy plugin to infer copy number variation (CNV) from single-cell transcriptomics data.

When trying to annotate genomic positions in Jupyter using infercnvpy, I get the following error. How can I fix things?

> ---
>
> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
> Cell In[28], line 2
> 1 gtf_file=r'G:\gencode.v38.annotation.gtf'
> 2 cnv.io.genomic_position_from_gtf(gtf_file, adata=adata, gtf_gene_id='gene_name', inplace=True)
>
> File ~\Anaconda3\envs\spapros\lib\site-packages\infercnvpy\io_genepos.py:41, in genomic_position_from_gtf(gtf_file, adata, gtf_gene_id, adata_gene_id, inplace)
> 11 def genomic_position_from_gtf(
> 12     gtf_file: Union[Path, str],
> 13     adata: Union[AnnData, None] = None,
> (...)
> 17     inplace: bool = True,
> 18 ) -> Union[pd.DataFrame, None]:
> 19     """Get genomic gene positions from a GTF file.
> 20
> 21     The GTF file needs to match the genome annotation used for your single cell dataset.
> (...)
> 39         If True, add the annotations directly to adata, otherwise return a dataframe.
> 40     """
> 41     gtf = gtfparse.read_gtf(
> 42         gtf_file, usecols=["seqname", "feature", "start", "end", "gene_id", "gene_name"], result_type="pandas"
> 43     )
> 44     gtf = (
> 45         gtf.loc[
> 46             gtf["feature"] == "gene",
> (...)
> 50         .rename(columns={"seqname": "chromosome"})
> 51     )
> 53     gene_ids_adata = (adata.var_names if adata_gene_id is None else adata.var[adata_gene_id]).values
>
> File ~\Anaconda3\envs\spapros\lib\site-packages\gtfparse\read_gtf.py:254, in read_gtf(filepath_or_buffer, expand_attribute_column, infer_biotype_column, column_converters, usecols, features, result_type)
> 251     raise ValueError("GTF file does not exist: %s" % filepath_or_buffer)
> 253 if expand_attribute_column:
> 254     result_df = parse_gtf_and_expand_attributes(
> 255         filepath_or_buffer,
> 256         restrict_attribute_columns=usecols,
> 257         features=features)
> 258 else:
> 259     result_df = parse_gtf(result_df, features=features)
>
> File ~\Anaconda3\envs\spapros\lib\site-packages\gtfparse\read_gtf.py:189, in parse_gtf_and_expand_attributes(filepath_or_buffer, restrict_attribute_columns, features)
> 166 def parse_gtf_and_expand_attributes(
> 167         filepath_or_buffer,
> 168         restrict_attribute_columns=None,
> 169         features=None):
> 170     """
> 171     Parse lines into column->values dictionary and then expand
> 172     the 'attribute' column into multiple columns. This expansion happens
> (...)
> 187         Ignore entries which don't correspond to one of the supplied features
> 188     """
> 189     df = parse_gtf(
> 190         filepath_or_buffer=filepath_or_buffer,
> 191         features=features,
> 192         split_attributes=True)
> 193     if type(restrict_attribute_columns) is str:
> 194         restrict_attribute_columns = {restrict_attribute_columns}
>
> File ~\Anaconda3\envs\spapros\lib\site-packages\gtfparse\read_gtf.py:155, in parse_gtf(filepath_or_buffer, split_attributes, features, fix_quotes_columns)
> 150 def parse_gtf(
> 151         filepath_or_buffer,
> 152         split_attributes=True,
> 153         features=None,
> 154         fix_quotes_columns=["attribute"]):
> 155     df_lazy = parse_with_polars_lazy(
> 156         filepath_or_buffer=filepath_or_buffer,
> 157         split_attributes=split_attributes,
> 158         features=features,
> 159         fix_quotes_columns=fix_quotes_columns)
> 160     return df_lazy.collect()
>
> File ~\Anaconda3\envs\spapros\lib\site-packages\gtfparse\read_gtf.py:87, in parse_with_polars_lazy(filepath_or_buffer, split_attributes, features, fix_quotes_columns)
> 80 def parse_with_polars_lazy(
> 81         filepath_or_buffer,
> 82         split_attributes=True,
> (...)
> 85     # use a global string cache so that all strings get intern'd into
> 86     # a single numbering system
> 87     polars.toggle_string_cache(True)
> 88     kwargs = dict(
> 89         has_header=False,
> 90         sep="\t",
> (...)
> 103             "frame": polars.UInt32,
> 104         })
> 105     try:
>
> AttributeError: module 'polars' has no attribute 'toggle_string_cache'

I've run the code below. I'm using the latest GENCODE GTF.

> import infercnvpy as cnv
> import scanpy as sc
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
> import pandas as pd
>
> adata=sc.read(r'G:\data.h5ad')
> sc.pp.log1p(adata)
>
> gtf_file=r'G:\gencode.v44.annotation.gtf'
> cnv.io.genomic_position_from_gtf(gtf_file, adata=adata, gtf_gene_id='gene_name', inplace=True)`

I'm doing this so I can get an output along the following lines, and proceed to running inferCNV

> adata.var.loc[:, ["ensg", "chromosome", "start", "end"]].head()

```
    ensg    chromosome  start   end
symbol              
AL645933.5  ENSG00000288587.1   chr6    31400702    31463705
AC010184.1  ENSG00000288585.1   chr3    141449745   141456434
AC023296.1  ENSG00000288580.1   chr8    2923568 2926689
AL117334.2  ENSG00000288577.1   chr20   3406380 3410036
AC107294.4  ENSG00000288576.1   chr3    184778723   184780720
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an error that's from `read_gtf` in the gtfparse library. I'm getting the same error with the latest version (which switched to using polars). Downgrading to an earlier version with `pip install gtfparse==1.3.0` fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I've created an issue on the gtfparse github repo for this: https://github.com/openvax/gtfparse/issues/41